# JDBC RollBack After Connection Close

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, transactions

Say a connection is opened and auto commit is set to false to start a transaction. After the transaction is complete, I would like to rollback any changes to bring the database to the state it was before I started the transaction.

My problem is, that during the transaction the connection is closed, and thus all the changes are committed at that time.

Is there a way to rollback the state of the database to before the initial transaction started?

and yes I've tried using Savepoints to no avail.

Comment: Are you using Oracle? AFAIK, it is one of the few drivers that commits instead of rolls back on connection close.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you're doing, why and how.

- If you have a reference to the transaction, you can rollback yourself.
- If not, can you throw an exception at the end?
- If all you want is to test things, why not use an embedded DB like H2 and start from scratch each time?
- If H2 doesn't cut it, check out [testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java).

Comment: unfortunately I'm sort of stuck testing this way, using nothing but JDBC library. I have my tests, and before them I start a transaction, and after I rollback. The code that I am testing is set up to close the connection after each insert, update, etc...